# Integral of the product of an bounded and any continous functions

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, lebesgue-integral

If $u:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is bounded measurable function so that for all $v\in C[0,1]$

$$\int_0^1uvdx=0$$then show that u is zero almost everywhere on $[0,1].$

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Can you share what you've tried, and explain what's giving you trouble?

Comment: I tried by contradiction, I assumed that If f is not zero on some set E of positive measure, then I could use property of the continuity of $v$ to arrive a contradiction, yet trouble will occur if the set E does not contain any interval (then I can not use continuity)

Comment: Hint: If $u \in C[0, 1]$, $v = u$ would force $u = 0$. So Lusin's theorem could be useful - measurable implies almost continuous

Comment: Ohh! I have just focused on wrong things, now I solved the problem, thank you hot_quen

Comment: What is $f$? This was never defined.

Comment: f = u. I tried to edit the question but this horrible website won't let me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $u$ is bounded and measurable, we have $u \in L^2[0,1]$. Since $L^2[0,1]$ is the completion of $C[0,1]$ with respect to the 'inner product' norm, we can find $u_n \in C[0,1]$ such that $u_n \to u$. Since $u_n$ is continuous, we have $\int u_n u  = 0$, and since $| \int (u-u_n)u | \le \|u-u_n\| \|u\|$, we see that
$\lim_n \int u_n u = \int u^2 = 0$. Hence $u(t) = 0$ ae. $t$.

If $u \in L^1[0,1]$ instead, we can apply a different technique. The function $\sigma(t) = 1_{[a,b]}(t)$ can be approximated (with the $\|\cdot\|_1$ norm) by uniformly bounded, continuous $\sigma_n$ so that $\sigma_n(t) \to \sigma(t)$ ae. $t$.
The dominated convergence theorem shows that $\lim_n \int u \sigma_n = \int u \sigma = \int_a^b u$. Since the $u_n$ are continuous, we have $\int_a^b u = 0$ for all $a,b \in [0,1]$. By considering the function $g(x) = \int_0^x u$, the Lebesgue differentiation theorem gives $g'(x) = u(x) $ ae. $x$, from which it follows that $u(x) = 0 $ ae. $x$.

Comment: Cool proof, thank you very much, what if we change the condition "u is bounded measurable" with "u is only integtrable measurable function", This question is the second part of my question  which could not solve it yet

Comment: I added a proof for the general integrable case.

Comment: :) thank you very much! cool approach